# Chrome Extension : How do I get previous entries and list them on the pop-up? / FIXED

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I've been trying to learn how to code a Chrome Extension with Javascript and I am stuck now so I would like your help please :)

What am I trying to do is to list comments/memos inside the extension popup.

The comment (input value) is store in localStorage.

```js
    function hello()
            {
            var greetings = "";

            if(localStorage['comment']){
                    var addComment = localStorage['comment'];
                }else{
                    addComment = "";
                };
       
            greetings = 'Your post : ' + addComment;

            return greetings;
            };

    function createIntro(){
        var content = document.createElement("div");
        content.style.width = '220px';
        content.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hello, " + hello()));
        container.appendChild(content); 

        return content;
    }

    var container = document.getElementById("intro");

    document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click",function(e){
        localStorage['comment'] = document.getElementById('comment').value;
    var commentList = createIntro();
    container.insertBefore(commentList, container.firstChild); 
    e.preventDefault();
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>extension</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Write anything"/>
    <input type="button" value="save" id="submit"/>
    
    <div id="intro"></div>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

So far I've only managed to get the last entry displayed but it's not what I want.
Now I can list them when I click on the save button but when I close the popup and open it again they aren't here :(

Is there anyone who can point me to the right direction and tell me what I'm missing please ?

Thank you ! :)

Comment: Without seeing the HTML I can only guess you have a form and input with type="summit" which is for servers, but an extension page is just a file so it simply reloads on submitting and nothing gets done. You need to either use a normal button or simply prevent the event by adding `e` parameter in the listener and then `e. preventDefault()`. Otherwise it's not clear what happens. Make sure you're debugging it in the correct devtools:  right-click the popup and click "inspect".

Comment: Thank @wOxxOm for your answer. Yes I use a normal button.
I forgot the preventDefault() I'll try that ;)

Comment: @wOxxOm Still does not work. Don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: @wOxxOm Oh yes no sorry I just copy/pasted the preventDefault() line and forgot to copy/paste the parameter but I did right on my computer and I don't have any error with the extension. Thanks ;)

Comment: Fixed! Found the solution : inputs are stored in an array which is saved on localStorage.